# Purpose of ConstraintLayout's setDesignInformation method

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

What would be an hypothetical use of the `get`/`setDesignInformation` methods included in the `ConstraintLayout` class?

The first parameter, `type`, must be equal to `0` to persist the values provided whereas the second parameter, `name`, has a logic to accept the string provided after the character `/` (if any).

Source code [here](https://cs.android.com/androidx/constraintlayout/+/main:constraintlayout/constraintlayout/src/main/java/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout.java;l=534)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called by `setChildrenConstraints()` in [two blocks](https://cs.android.com/androidx/constraintlayout/+/main:constraintlayout/constraintlayout/src/main/java/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout.java;l=1181-1215?q=setDesignInformation&ss=androidx%2Fconstraintlayout), one tied to `isInEditMode` and one tied to a `DEBUG` flag.

The `isInEditMode` block has this comment:

```
        // In design mode, let's make sure we keep track of the ids; in Studio, a build step
        // might not have been done yet, so asking the system for ids can break. So to be safe,
        // we save the current ids, which helpers can ask for.
```

So, this is probably to help the Android Studio designer and possibly the new widget preview option.